Error Error sending packet to decoder -1094995529 when extracting audio from MP4 using FFmpeg C API
I am trying to extract audio from an MP4 file and save it as an MP3 using the FFmpeg C API. My code is able to identify the audio stream, set up the codec contexts, and start reading packets. However, I encounter an error when sending packets to the decoder.
Purpose of the Code:

Open the input video file and retrieve the stream information.
Identify the audio stream and set up decoding with the appropriate codec.
Set up the output format for the MP3 file and configure codec parameters.
Read packets from the input file and send them to the decoder.

Here's the part of the code that reads packets and sends them to the decoder:
    // read packets
    AVFrame *pframe = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!pframe)
        return (printf("Could not allocate packet frame\n"), 1);
    AVPacket pkt;
    while (1)
    {
        if (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt) < 0)
            break;
        printf("packet stream index %d\n", pkt.stream_index);
        if ((pkt.stream_index) == audio_stream_index)
        {
            printf("packet size %d\n", pkt.size);
            int ret = avcodec_send_packet(cd_ctx, &pkt);
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                printf("EAGAIN or EOF\n");
            else if (ret < 0)
                return (printf("Error sending packet to decoder %d\n", ret), 1);
        }
    }


Error output:
format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 duration 2.550000
nb of streams 2
stream 0 => id: 1 => type: video
stream 1 => id: 2 => type: audio
audio stream index 1
Output #0, mp3, to 'audio.mp3':
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    reading packets....
packet stream index 0
packet stream index 0
packet stream index 1
packet size 371
Error sending packet to decoder -1094995529


What could be causing this error, and how can I correct it? Any guidance on proper handling of packets with FFmpeg’s C API would be greatly appreciated.
Full code for context:
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define RED "\033[0;31m"
#define GREEN "\033[0;32m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    if (ac != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <input file> <output file>\n", av[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    AVCodec *codec = NULL;
    AVCodecContext *cd_ctx = NULL;
    AVOutputFormat *out_format = NULL;
    AVFormatContext *out_ctx = NULL;
    AVCodec *out_codec = NULL;
    AVStream *in_stream = NULL, *out_stream = NULL;

    // allocate format context
    AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!fmt_ctx)
        return (printf("Could not allocate format context\n"), 1);

    // open input file
    if (avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, av[1], NULL, NULL) != 0)
        return (printf("Could not open input file\n"), 1);

    printf("format %s duration %f\n",
            fmt_ctx->iformat->name,
            (double)(fmt_ctx->duration / 1000000) / (double)60);
    
    // get stream info
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, NULL) < 0)
        return (printf("Could not get stream info\n"), 1);
    
    printf("nb of streams %d\n", fmt_ctx->nb_streams);
    int audio_stream_index = -1;
    // loop through streams
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        printf("stream %d => id: %d => type: ", i, fmt_ctx->streams[i]->id);
        // check stream type
        if (fmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            printf("audio\n");

            audio_stream_index = i;
            printf("audio stream index %d\n", audio_stream_index);
        }
        else if (fmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            printf("video\n");
        else
            printf("other\n");
    }


    // get codec
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(fmt_ctx->streams[audio_stream_index]->codecpar->codec_id);
    if (!codec)
        return (printf("Could not find codec\n"), 1);

    // allocate codec context
    cd_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!cd_ctx)
        return (printf("Could not allocate codec context\n"), 1);
    
    // open codec
    if (avcodec_open2(cd_ctx, codec, NULL) < 0)
        return (printf("Could not open codec\n"), 1);
    
    // get codec format
    out_format = av_guess_format(NULL, av[2], NULL);
    if (!out_format)
        return (printf("Could not guess out format\n"), 1);

    // allocate output context
    out_ctx = NULL;
    if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(&out_ctx, NULL, NULL, av[2]) < 0)
        return (printf("Could not allocate context for output\n"), 1);

    // find encoder for output format
    out_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(out_format->audio_codec);
    if (!out_codec)
        return (printf("Could not find encoder\n"), 1);
    
    in_stream = fmt_ctx->streams[audio_stream_index];

    // create new stream
    if ((out_stream = avformat_new_stream(out_ctx, out_codec)) == NULL)
        return (printf("Could not create new stream\n"), 1);
    
    // Fill output codec context with desired sample rate, sample fmt, channel etc.
    AVCodecParameters *in_codecpar = in_stream->codecpar;
    AVCodecParameters *out_codecpar = out_stream->codecpar;
    int ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(out_codecpar, in_codecpar);
    if (ret < 0)
        return (printf("Could not copy codec parameters\n"), 1);

    // Set codec ID to MP3
    out_codecpar->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_MP3;

    // Ensure codec parameters match MP3 requirements
    out_codecpar->format = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP; // Set to a format suitable for MP3
    out_codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO;
    out_codecpar->sample_rate = 44100; // Set the desired sample rate, e.g., 44100 Hz
    out_codecpar->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO; // Stereo layout
    out_codecpar->channels = 2; // Number of audio channels

    av_dump_format(out_ctx, 0, av[2], 1);

    // open output file
    if (avio_open(&out_ctx->pb, av[2], AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) > 0)
        return (printf("Could not open out file\n"), 1);
    
    // write headers
    if (avformat_write_header(out_ctx, NULL) < 0)
        return (printf("Could not write headers\n"), 1);
    

    printf("\treading packets....\n");


    // read packets
    AVFrame *pframe = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!pframe)
        return (printf("Could not allocate packet frame\n"), 1);
    AVPacket pkt;
    while (1)
    {
        if (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt) < 0)
            break;
        printf("packet stream index %d\n", pkt.stream_index);
        if ((pkt.stream_index) == audio_stream_index)
        {
            printf("packet size %d\n", pkt.size);
            int ret = avcodec_send_packet(cd_ctx, &pkt);
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                printf("EAGAIN or EOF\n");
            else if (ret < 0)
                return (printf("Error sending packet to decoder %d\n", ret), 1);
        }
    }

    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}



The error is Invalid data found when processing input. Does the ffmpeg cli process the file fine?

@Gyan yes it is processed fine. The problem is in the code.

@SaadOut03 (1) What's the audio codec in the MP4? Telling us the name/type might give us a clue about the error. (2) You want to be doing an AAC to MP3 encoding. Note that AAC is actually MP3 "version 2". You could just mux from MP4 into M4A to keep the higher quality AAC from MP4. Depends on ears.. (3) The FFmpeg CLI will make intelligent decisions based on the input file and that's why it works. An example is: Maybe it sees that the input .mp4 is really just a renamed .mov so now it adjusts to decode MOV and works, but your code is not doing such a check and sends data  to wrong decoder.

Where are you receiving the frames?
